# Table analysis in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` and I need to create `TABLE_B_FINAL`.
 **Rule:** 
If in `TABLE_A` the value of `ID_C=1` and value of `AB=AFTER` we will multiply the value of `WEIGHT` with corresponding value in `TABLE_B` (row `ID_C=1` and column `AFTER`). 
**Next examples:**
If in `TABLE_A` the value of `ID_C=1` and value of `AB=BEFORE` we will multiply the value of `WEIGHT` with corresponding value in `TABLE_B` (row `ID_C=1` and column `BEFORE`). 
If in `TABLE_A` the value of `ID_C=2` and value of `AB=AFTER` we will multiply the value of `WEIGHT` with corresponding value in `TABLE_B` (row `ID_C=2` and column `AFTER`).
This algorithm check all records in `TABLE_A` and multliply their value of `WEIGHT` with corresponding value in `TABLE_B`.
 At the beginning `TABLE_B` has default value `1` in all rows and columns(`AFTER` and `BEFORE`). This value will change during multiplications.

**TABLE_A**

```
ID_N|WEIGHT_N|ID_C |AB        |
5   |1.15    | 1   |AFTER     |
12  |1.13    | 1   |BEFORE    |
60  |1.65    | 3   |AFTER     |
90  |1.85    | 2   |AFTER     |
80  |1.45    | 3   |AFTER     |
140 |1.57    | 2   |BEFORE    |
```

**TABLE_B**

```
|ID_C |BEFORE|AFTER|
|1    |1     | 1   |
|2    |1     | 1   |
|3    |1     | 1   |
```

**TABLE_B_FINAL**

```
|ID_C |BEFORE      |AFTER            |
|1    |1*1.13=1.13 | 1*1.15=1.15     |
|2    |1,57        | 1,85            |
|3    |1           | 1*1.65*1.45=2.39|
```

Comment: Please show us your SQL scripts and table schema, things you have done so far.

Comment: My idea is to make a first cycle which run througth TABLE_A and search for ID_C=1,2,3,....n and second cycle which will be inside first cycle and recognize if the value is AFTER or BEFORE. But I am dont know how to do it.

Comment: You don't need to cycle or loop. Just retrieve the correct values, based on the value of table_a.ab. And you might need the recursive query to calculate the product : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36201120/2235885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select TABLE_B.ID_C AS ID_C, BEFORE = 
  CASE TABLE_C.AB
    WHEN 'BEFORE' THEN TABLE_B.BEFORE*TABLE_C.WEIGHT_N
    ELSE TABLE_B.BEFORE
  END,
AFTER =
  CASE TABLE_C.AB 
    WHEN 'AFTER' THEN TABLE_B.AFTER*TABLE_C.WEIGHT_N
    ELSE TABLE_B.AFTER
  END
FROM (SELECT ID_C, AB, EXP(SUM(ln(WEIGHT_N))) FROM TABLE_A GROUP BY ID_C, AB) as TABLE_C
JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_B.ID_C=TABLE_C.ID_C;
```